# Как выдать права в laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, авторизация, auth, права

Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли в Ларавеле возможность выдачи прав, или этот функционал надо допиливать самостоятельно? 
Если самостоятельно, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, ссылки на статьи про это.

Answer (score 1):

В самом фреймворке сделан ACL, почитать про нег оможете здесь: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization

А вот RBAC это уже только подключать компонент, я бы советовал: 
https://packagist.org/packages/dcn/rbac

Так же я писал свой RBAC для Laravel 5.3 но не сделал readme, можете установить и спрашивать если будут вопросы:

https://packagist.org/packages/yaroslavmolchan/rbac